# Constraining FindFit to a range

Tags: fitting, constraint

I'm trying to fit data, that I obtained from measurements, to a theoretical model. The way I see it, `FindFit` or `NonlinearModelfit` try to fit the model to the data on the whole range. In my case it's a function of time. But I only want to work on the range that i actually have data for. Say for $0 < t < 10$. Is there any way to do this? I tried using a constraint in the model like

```
FindFit[Data, {model, t < 10}, parameters, t]
```

but it does not work.

Comment: ...and yet you show us neither the data nor the model? What are we supposed to do, then?

Comment: That's not quite how fitting works. The fitting will only use the data it has, and no other. Of course, if the resulting fitted model has values elsewhere, you can calculate such values, but the fit procedure won't care. On the other hand, if you want to fit a model only to a portion of your existing data, then pre-select the appropriate data before feeding it to the `Fit` function (look up e.g. `Part`, `Select`, `Cases`...). In short, you should really show the data, the model, and specify *in detail* what problem you are having. "It doesn't work" is not informative enough for us to help.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
FindFit[Select[Data, First[#] < 10 &], model, parameters, t]
```